# Why subdataWithRange leads to Memory Leak in any NSThread?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am confused by this. I thought ARC can handle the memory here. The subData is never used after this if statement.

```
    if ([_buffer length] >= _bufferSize) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, _bufferSize);
        NSData *subData = [_buffer subdataWithRange:range];
        // Call the delegate method to deal with the new data
        [_delegate inputQueue:self inputData:subData numberOfPackets:inNumberPacketDescriptions];
        // Remove the transmitted data
        [_buffer replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:NULL length:0];
    }
```

But the call to `subdataWithRange` leads to a memory leak. The `subData` is never released. I found someone said that subdataWithRange will definitely lead to memory leak under NSThread. But why?

The buffer is from AudioQueue and this function is called when one of the Queues inside AudioQueue is filled up. This code should be running on an internal thread of AudioQueue.

By adding an autoreleasepool, the leak is solved. But why...

```
if ([_buffer length] >= _bufferSize) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, _bufferSize);
        NSData *subData = [_buffer subdataWithRange:range];
        // Call the delegate method to deal with the new data
        [_delegate inputQueue:self inputData:subData numberOfPackets:inNumberPacketDescriptions];
        // Remove the transmitted data
        [_buffer replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:NULL length:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you detecting the memory leak? Instruments?  Where is the source of your buffer data coming from?  I just generated some random data using malloc/free combination (to use garbage data) and ran subDataWithRange via a loop, using instruments to detect leaks and didn't see any issues.

Comment: @R4N I am using instrument and actually it is not marked by a leak, but the memory usage is keep increasing. I am using an AudioQueue service, and the buffer comes from AudioQueue. This code should be called in the internal thread of AudioQueue, I am not sure it this is the cause.

Comment: @R4N I do see a blog saying that using subdataWithRange in NSThread cause a memory leak. It seems that AudioQueue gives each queue an NSThread to run. But if I can use autoreleasepool to stop the memory increasing, it is not a "memory leak" for real, but something wrong with the autorelease part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All NSThreads leak in this way. NSThreads do not have their own autorelease pool. The first thing you must *always* do when performing on any thread except the main thread is create an autorelease pool. Of course it is better never to use NSThread in the first place. That is why there is GCD.

Comment: If the NSThead inside AudioQueue is terminated, if no autoreleasepool added, should I expect the main autorelease pool to handle the autorelease inside those threads?

Comment: No, I wouldn’t expect that.